# `DbSet<T>.Find` returns "incomplete" `T`

Tags: entity-framework

Currently, we are using `Where` followed by `First` to fetch items from the DB by key:

```
DbSet<DerivedResource> dbSet = GetDBSet();
DerivedResource resource = dbSet.Where(r => r.Guid == guid).Include(r => r.Data).First();
```

This works, this takes a long time. I assume that the call is O(n) and that there is no magic taking place behind the scenes to optimize the call. So, in the attempt to speed things up, I used this instead:

```
DerivedResource resource = dbSet.Find(guid);
```

This is quick, but results in `resource` missing some data: the `Data` property is `null`. How can I either fill in this data, or otherwise quickly retrieve an item by key?

Following is a sketch of the classes I'm using. I suspect that the fact that `DerivedResource : BaseResource` doesn't matter:

```
[Table("DerivedResource")]
public class DerivedResource : BaseResource<DerivedResource>
{
    public BaseData Data { get; set; }
}

[Table("DerivedResource_BaseData")]
public abstract class BaseData
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("DerivedResourceGuid")]
    public DerivedResource DerivedResource { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [Key]
    [Required, Column("DerivedResourceID")]
    public Guid DerivedResourceGuid { get; set; }
}

[Table("DerivedResource_BaseData_DerivedData")]
public class DerivedData : BaseData { }

public abstract class BaseResource<T>
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public virtual void DoSomething<T>(T t) { }
}
```

I am new to Entity and would really appreciate the help. I am using EF 6. (If anything is particularly easier with EF Core, I wouldn't mind hearing.)

Comment: `dbSet.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Guid == guid).Include(r => r.Data);` Won't even compile.  And the model is a little strange.  Can you improve the question to contain a complete repro of the issue?

Comment: Whoops. I mistranslated the query. I'm unsure of what a "complete repro" includes. The actual model has classes six levels of base classes. Surely you'd rather see an condensed form?

Comment: If you have a TPT model with six levels of base classes, that might be the cause of the performance problem.  But something like `dbSet.Include(r => r.Data).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Guid == guid);` is the right way to do eager loading.

Comment: That is a variant I hadn't tried yet. However, it doesn't improve things. It is taking ~30ms for `dbSet.Include(r => r.Data).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Guid == guid)` compared to ~2ms for `dbSet.Find(guid)`. Here's why I don't think it is the complexity of the model causing the slowness: `dbSet.Find(guid)` has to deal with the same model, and manages it in less than a tenth of the time (but missing 1 property value). Besides, by default `FirstOrDefault` is O(n), whereas requesting an item from the DB by key should be O(1).

Comment: If you Include navigation property with `n` releated entities, they each have to be fetched, materialized and added to the ChangeTracker, so O(n).  The database query may not be O(n), but the entity retrieval and materialization will be.  30ms sounds reasonable.

Comment: Yikes. Is the answer then that there is no way to do an O(1) fetch and then fill out the missing data after the fact?

Comment: The cost of fetching entities is a function of how many entities you fetch.  That's why it's O(n).  Fetching 10000 entities is always going to be much more expensive than fetching 100.

Comment: I only want 1 item. I don't know how the Microsoft Entity framework works under the hood, but I assume that for primary keys there would be some sort of hashing scheme for quick access of individual entities.

Comment: Does the Entity framework have O(1) access by primary key?